# mailto: valid address doesn't prompt mail app?

Tags: html-email, mailto, responsys

I'm trying to include a mailto link to a specific email address within the body copy of my HTML email.

For some reason, this particular email address does not register with my mailing app. My HTML here is:

`<a href="mailto:feedback@(workplace).com">here</a>`

and when I click the link, it opens a blank page and doesn't do anything.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdlIl.jpg

If I change the email address to be my own email address or feedack@(workplace).com or even misspelling the domain as feedback@(workplac).com, the mailing app registers this activity and I get a pop-up window. Any ideas why the particular email address, feedback@(workplace).com, doesn't work that way?

Thanks in advance for any advice or insight.

Comment: What are you showing in the screenshot? It doesn’t look like an HTML link.

Comment: The screenshot is part of the resulting URL after I click the link. It's redirecting from Responsys (an email service platform). I ruled out Responsys as a problem by swapping out the feedback@(workplace).com link with different email addresses. Other email addresses are prompting the mail app pop-up, just not the feedback@(workplace).com address.

Comment: Your link seems to be tracked (added UTM in the end and something else appended). Are you able to disable tracking on that specific link only?

Answer (score 0):

are you working on a BIF or RPL account in responsys? I normaly use the `Clickthrough()` function in responsys and place the link in the linktable.

```
HTML
<a href="${clickthrough('mailtoMe')}">Write to me</a>


LINK TABLE
Name: mailtoMe
Url: mailto:feedback@(workplace).com
```

Comment: I'm using the classic version. I tried the method you described, but that didn't work for me either, suggesting the problem was with the feedback@(workplace).com address.

It turns out feedback@(workplace).com is an email distribution list. I'm not sure if that has any impact on this issue, but using singular emails like myname@(workplace).com works.